# Alpine docker autofs install for dynamic dotnet cifs access

Tags: docker, mount, cifs, autofs, alpine

I am trying to access a network share with specific credentials. It's to be used from a dotnet application that I am running in docker. My research conclusion is that autofs is the best way to do dynamic mount, but I am open to any other solution to do the same thing. I realise asp.net alpine might be a bit of a slim base image choice here but I have a strong preference for it for security reasons.

I am having trouble figuring out why autofs won't install/start, it fails quietly/or I don't know where to look for logs or any output what so ever.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.15-alpine3.17 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.407-alpine3.17 AS build
# --Here goes the dotnet build, removed for breivety--
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]    # Needed for openrc?
RUN apk -q add openrc samba-client autofs cifs-utils #samba-client::smbclient is used for debugging
RUN chmod +x ./docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
echo -e "username=$DfsShare__Domain/$DfsShare__Username\npassword=$DfsShare__Password" > /etc/.dfs-credentials

mkdir $DfsShare__LocalDir
echo "$DfsShare__LocalDir -fstype=cifs,credentials=/etc/.dfs-credentials ://$DfsShare__Server/$DfsShare__Share" > /etc/auto.mydfs
echo "/-      /etc/auto.mydfs" >> /etc/autofs/auto.master
rc-service autofs restart
dotnet WebService.dll
```

The mount is not done, and autofs service seems to be failing. I have the following output after startup:

```
* WARNING: autofs is already starting
```

Some things I've tried to get more info:

Verified that all variables `$DfsShare__Domain` etc are ok - docker-compose fills them out and I can use them with smbclient

Output of `rc-status`:

```
Runlevel: sysinit
Dynamic Runlevel: hotplugged
Dynamic Runlevel: needed/wanted
Dynamic Runlevel: manual
```

Testing with smbclient from docker works fine using the following command:

```
smbclient //$DfsShare__Server/$DfsShare__Share -m SMB2 -U $DfsShare__Domain/$DfsShare__Username%$DfsShare__Password -c "get TestFiles\\10MB.dat 10MB.dat"
```

Some pages refer to `/etc/sysconfig/autofs` and to set `AUTOFS_OPTIONS="--debug"` in this file , but it does not seem to be present in this image even after install of autofs (should I create it?!)

Also I've seen references to `/var/log/messages` but it's not present either and I'm not sure how to/if possible to activate it.